# How to generate Entity Framework or Linq To SQL wrappers for system stored procedures?

Tags: .net, sql-server, linq-to-sql, entity-framework

I want to be able to work with system stored procedures (sp_helpXXX etc) through generated Linq-To-SQL or Entity Framework wrappers.  Problem is, system sprocs are not listed in the generation wizards.  I have also tried running sqlmetal.exe manually, but no system stored procedures show up.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there is automatic way, but in linq2sql you can define stored procedures and function by hand on the partial class of the data context.

Here is one I use for the sql's GetDate function (which I can use in the linq query expressions):

```
[Function(Name = "GetDate", IsComposable = true)]
public DateTime GetSystemDate()
{
    MethodInfo mi = MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod() as MethodInfo;
    return (DateTime)this.ExecuteMethodCall(this, mi, new object[] { }).ReturnValue;
}
```

The same principle applies for Stored Procedure (add a regular stored procedure through the designer, and check it out in the generated code).

Answer (score 0):

here's a thorough write up that walks through entity framework basics. Adding stored procs is definitely not straightforward but will seem a breeze if you've tried this in nHibernate. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg699321.aspx